# How can I improve Commonwealth load time in Fallout 4 (PC)?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, fallout-4

I love Fallout 4 but I absolutely loathe going into buildings because every time I come out, re-loading the Commonwealth takes a very long time (a minute or more).  This can't be an issue w/ my PC because it's a high-end gaming rig and this is a 5 year-old game.

Initial load times are fine.
Loading a save game is fine (even saves in the Commonwealth).
Entering areas (even complex ones like Diamond City or Goodneighbor) are fine also.

I ONLY experience the problem when leaving a building or an area and it has to re-load the commonwealth. It's so bad, I literally have time to get up, go to the bathroom, and come back to my chair before it's done.

I thought maybe it might be an issue with my save file, so I backed it up and deleted the entire save/settings folder to make the whole game start fresh.  Nope. The first quest in Concord has you entering/exiting the Museum of Freedom a couple times and it's just terrible.

Computer specs:
8-core i9
32GB RAM
2TB EVO 970 SSD (NVMe)
Vega 64 video card
2560x1440 Dell IPS display, 60Hz
Windows 10 1909 Enterprise